# whoe to solve this proplem :updating a chiled component in vuejs update all the other childeren?

Tags: vue.js

I want to update the likes for the specific comment
this is the parent component Commnet.vue

```
<template>
    <v-list class="list" color="white" three-line>
      <template v-for="cmnt in comments" class="mb-2">
        <v-card color="transparent" class=" text-no-wrap" :key="cmnt._id">
          <v-list-item class="item" :key="cmnt._id">
            <v-list-item-avatar>
              <v-img :src="cmnt.author.image"></v-img>
            </v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-list-item-content class="black--text">
              <v-list-item-title>{{
                cmnt.author.first_name + " " + cmnt.author.last_name
              }}</v-list-item-title>
              <v-list-item-subtitle class="black--text" v-html="cmnt.comment">
                {{ cmnt.comment }}
              </v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
            <v-card class="like-count">
              <v-icon color="blue">mdi-thumb-up </v-icon>
              <Likes :_id="cmnt._id"/>
            </v-card>
          </v-list-item>  
        </v-card>

        <v-card
          :key="cmnt._id"
          outlined="true"
          color="transparent"
          class="ml-6"
        >
</template>
```

and this is the child component inside comment component it has it is own state completely separated form the parent.

Like.vue

```
<template>
     <div>
       <v-card >

       </v-card>
       {{likes.length}}
     </div>

</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

import io from "socket.io-client";
export default {
    name:"Likes",
    created:async function(){
      axios.get(`comment/${this._id}`)
      .then(results=>{
        if (results.data){
            this.likes =results.data;
        }
      })
      .catch(err=> console.log(err));

      let url = "";
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
      url = "/";
    } else {
      url = "http://localhost:5000";
    }
    this.socket = io(url);

 this.socket.on("receive-like",async  (data)=>{
      console.log(data)
      this.new_like= data;
      console.log(this.new_like)
      const el = this.likes.find(el => el._id === this.new_like._id)
    if (el){
      const index = this.likes.indexOf(el);
      this.$forceUpdate()

     return this.likes.splice(index,1)
    }else{
      this.likes.push(this.new_like);
      console.log(this.likes)
      this.$forceUpdate()
    }

    })

    },
    mounted:async function(){

    },
    props:{
      _id:{
        type: String
      }
    },
    data:()=>({
      user:{},
      likes:[],
      new_like:{}
    }),
computed:{
 
},
    }
</script>
```

so when clicking like the new like object get pushed to the array of likes for the concerned comment but likes for all comments get updated at ones.

Answer (score 0):

in case somebody is wondering I just made adding the new like object conditional
if(data.comment._id === this._id)